# SQL to return results if multiple matches in a pivot table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
channel_data table
-------------
entry_id
content

channel_title table
-------------
entry_id
title

category_posts table
-------------
entry_id
category_id
```

sample data for category_posts

```
entry_id  cat_id
2         10
2         11
2         30
2         40
3         10
3         11
```

I need to be able to query the data so I can say return data that have multiple categories.  I have tried a few different ways but so far can't figure it out.  I am sure it is simple so hoping someone can help out.

Here is where I got but can't figure out what I need in the where clause to make it work.  If I only need one category it works but with 2 it does not.

```
SELECT distinct a.entry_id, b.title
FROM exp_channel_data as a 
LEFT JOIN exp_channel_titles as b
ON a.entry_id = b.entry_id
LEFT JOIN exp_category_posts as c
ON a.entry_id = c.entry_id
WHERE c.cat_id = 10 and c.cat_id = 30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a query like the following in order to get `entry_id` values being related to *both* `cat_id` values:

```
SELECT entry_id
FROM category_posts
WHERE cat_id IN (10, 30)
GROUP BY entry_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT cat_id) = 2
```

Now you can use the above query as a derived table and `JOIN` to it in order to get the expected result:

```
SELECT distinct a.entry_id, b.title
FROM exp_channel_data as a 
LEFT JOIN exp_channel_titles as b ON a.entry_id = b.entry_id
LEFT JOIN (
   ... above query here
) AS c ON a.entry_id = c.entry_id
```

Comment: This works great.  Just had to make the second left join a join as with a left it was giving me all entry_id results.  Thank You